# Members of Sharepoint group not receive Notification email, when you change members of the Email sending group after the workflow started

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I created a workflow in SharePoint 2010 & its works with couples Sharepoint Groups to send notification email and it’s working fine .

My problem comes After  Workflow Started, when Members of the  Sharepoint Groups is change after the workflow Started , workflow is not picking the new member changers in to send emails  ?

Is there a easy way to fix this problem ?

Really appreciate you help

Comment: Is there a programming question in there somewhere?  Or is this a product support inquiry?

Comment: Hi Kevin , txn for your reply.Actually I have done a workaround in sharepoint designer 2010 by calling user groups before each and every time email notification sending . it’s really a painful to manage the workflow !!! 
I was hopping is there a better way of handle the issue   . 

either way  progrmme or SP admin level 
cheers

Comment: Problems like this (I've found) are usually timer job related. I may be wrong, but I'd double check the frequency at which the timer jobs relevant to your user profile service are ran.